# Induction Proof for $F_{2n} = F^2_{n+1} - F^2_{n-1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

As stated in the tag, I'm trying to prove by induction the claim $F_{2n} = F^2_{n+1} - F^2_{n-1}$, where $F_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number. I've spent hours on the inductive step without substantial progress, and am hoping someone can provide a path to the desired result.

To facilitate the proof, we're given $F_{2n-1} = F^2_{n} + F^2_{n-1}$

(Also, in various past attempts not reflected here I tried to use the following substitutions whenever it seemed prudent: $F_{n} = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} = F_{n+1} - F_{n-1}$; and $(x^{2} - y^{2}) = (x - y)(x + y)$).

For the inductive step, let $n\geq 1$ and assume $F_{2n} = F^2_{n+1} - F^2_{n-1}$. For $n+1$ we want to show $F_{2(n+1)} = F^2_{n+2} - F^2_{n}$. So

\begin{align}
  F_{2(n+1)} &= F_{2n + 2} \\
             &= F_{2n+1} + F_{2n} \\
             &= (F_{2n} + F_{2n-1}) + F_{2n} \\
             &= 2 F_{2n} + F_{2n - 1} \\
             &= 2 (F^2_{n+1} - F^2_{n-1})
                  + F^2_{n} + F^2_{n-1} 
                     &&\text{by the inductive hypothesis} \tag{1} \\
             &=...F^2_{n+2} - F^2_{n}                     
\end{align}
I have two challenges.  The first is squeezing $-2 F^2_{n}$ out of (1).  The only reasonable way I can see to do that is to expand the $-F^2_{n-1}$ term in  $2 F^2_{n+1} - F^2_{n-1}$ to $-(F_{n} - F_{n-2})^2$. If in instead I combine it with $F^2_{n-1}$ then it seems impossible to generate the $-2 F^2_{n}$ term needed to offset $F^2_{n}$ and produce $-F^2_{n}$.

The second challenge is to find $(F^2_{n+2}$ in (1), and the only way I can see to do that is to expand the $F^2_{n+1}$ term in $2(F^2_{n+1} - F^2_{n-1})$to $(F_{n+2} - F_{n})^2$. Doing that not only generates $2 F^2_{n}$ which totally screws things up, but it also generates a bunch of intermediate terms I can't get rid of, and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: It is difficult to prove this result on its own. My advice is that you prove a more generalized result, and then derive this as a corollary

Comment: Prove this one first : F(n+m)= F(n)F(m-1) + F(n+1)F(m)

Comment: See also: [How to prove this Fibonacci sequence statement: $F^2_{n+1} - F^2_{n-1} = F_{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2690096)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1.** By induction on $n$ we have $F_n=(a^n-b^n)/\sqrt 5$ where $a=(1+\sqrt 5)/2$ and $b=(1-\sqrt 5)/2=-1/a.$ Plug this into your formula.

**Method 2.** Let $M$ be the $2\times2$ matrix with top row $(1,1)$ and bottom row $(1,0).$ By induction on $n,$  the top row of $M^n$ is $(F_{n+1},F_n)$ and the bottom row of $M^n$ is $(F_n,F_{n-1}).$ Consider that $M^{2 n} =(M^n)^2$.

**Method  3.** Your method. For brevity let $$F_{n-1}=a, \quad F_n=b,\quad F_{n+1}=c,\quad F_{n+2}=d.$$ From your 3rd line and the inductive hypothesis, and given $F_{2 n-1}=F_n^2+F_{n-1}^2$, we have $$F_{2 n+2}=2 F_{2 n}+F_{2 n-1}=2 (c^2-  a^2) +(b^2+a^2)=$$ $$=2 c^2+b^2-a^2 =2 (d-b)^2+b^2-(c-b)^2=$$ $$=2(d-b)^2 +b^2-((d-b)-b)^2=d^2-b^2=F_{n+2}^2-F_n^2.$$

Comment: Method 3 is the solution I need.  Thank you so much!  Looks like I was pretty close.  If I had expanded $(f_{n-1})^{2}$ to $(f_{n+2} - f_{n} - f_{n})^{2})$ I'd have gotten it (although it's doubtful I would have managed to square that term properly).

Comment: It also reminded me of something I clearly can't re-learn enough times:  simplify complex expressions with variables.

Comment: Even when writing on paper I try to change the symbols to $a,b,c,...$ and simplify as  much as I can or I tend to lose track of what I'm doing. Although once I tried to show someone how to rationalize the denominator in $1/(\sqrt 2-1)$, When I wrote $1/(\sqrt 2 -1)=(1+\sqrt 2+1)/((\sqrt 2-1)(\sqrt 2+1))$  he insisted that we must simplify by cancelling the upper and lower $(\sqrt 2+1)$.

Answer (score 6):

You're given $$f_{2n-1}=f_n^2+f_{n-1}^2\tag1$$ Replace $n$ with $n+1$ to get $$f_{2n+1}=f_{n+1}^2+f_n^2\tag2$$ Subtract (1) from (2) to get $$f_{2n+1}-f_{2n-1}=f_{n+1}^2-f_{n-1}^2\tag3$$ But the left side of (3) is $f_{2n}$.

Comment: Wow, was not expecting something so short and sweet

Comment: All the hard work is in proving (1), but since we're told we can just use (1)....

Comment: That's genius, although I can't use it.  The assignment specifies that we prove the claim by induction.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

As this is a difficult result to prove, I shall prove another result and then derive the said result through it.

**Proposition:** $F_{n+m} = F_n F_{m-1} + F_{n+1} F_m$

**Base cases:**  $n = 1$:

$\begin{align}
     F_{m+1} &= F_m + F_{m-1} \\
            &= F_2 F_m + F_1 F_{m-1}
  \end{align}$

Case $n = 2$:

$\begin{align}
   F_{m+2} 
     &= F_{m+1} + F_m \\
     &= F_{m-1} + 2 F_m \\
     &= F_2 F_{m-1} + F_3 F_m
\end{align}$

**Hypothesis:** $F_{k+m-1} = F_{k-1} F_{m-1} + F_k F_m$ and
$F_{k + m}   = F_k F_{m-1} + F_{k +1} F_m$

**Induction step:** Adding both the hypothesis statements

$\begin{align}
   F_{k + m + 1} &= F_{k+m} + F_{k+m-1} \\
                &=F_{k+1} F_{m-1} + F_{k+1+1} F_m
\end{align}$

Hence, proved.

$F_{n+m} = F_n F_{m-1} + F_{n+1} F_m$

Putting $n = m$:

$\begin{align}
   F_{2n} &= F_n F_{n-1} + F_{n+1} F_n \\
         &= (F_{n+1} - F_{n-1}) F_{n-1} + F_{n+1} F_n \\
         &= F_{n+1} F_{n-1} + F_{n+1} F_n - F^2_{n-1} \\
         &= F_{n+1}(F_{n-1} + F_n) - F^2_{n-1} \\
         &= F^2_{n+1} - F^2_{n-1}
\end{align}$

Comment: This is very nice.  Thank you!

Comment: @ScentlessApprentice Is this acceptable for your assignment ?

Comment: Absolutely, although it's beyond the scope of what I feel I'm capable of right now.  I was very close to the solution outlined in Method 3 presented by user254665, but got lost in the profusion of intermediate terms.

Comment: @ScentlessApprentice, I hope my edit clears up some...

Comment: @vonbrand Thanks for the edits. Do you know why the ending lines were coming in a very odd way inspite of there being dollar signs ?

Comment: No clue. MathJax is fickle... and I'm too accustomed to write LaTeX to make such mistakes.

Comment: Perhaps you should note (it isn't obvious) that you are doing *two* interleaved inductions, thus two base cases.

Comment: @von, you really went through all the posts in this thread and changed every $f$ to an $F$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes. Standard notation for Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @vonbrand I'm using strong induction, and require two base cases since I am using two hypothesis statements.

Comment: Hey @vonbrand, thanks for the edits.  Hope someone else finds all this great feedback as useful as I did.

Comment: @ScentlessApprentice, if you appreciate it, I'm fully paid. Thanks!